# How to Determine Network Speed using Javascript in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-phone-8

From what I have read, to determine network speed I need to download an image from the web with known file size, and then determine the time that this process took to get my variables for my Mbps calculation. My first question is, how would I download an image to Windows Phone using javascript? I am somewhat familiar with javascript functions now that I have been researching, but I am not sure how to tell the function where to save the image. Also, my guess is that I will use the Navigation API new to HTML5 to determine the time the download process takes. For this, which metrics should I use from the `window.performance.timing` to get this calculation. Currently I have a function made for each metric which I can return, but I am unsure of which to use in this calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JavaScript to test the performance, and I wouldn't recommend it. You can also use C# as shown below.

If you use the portable class [library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx) for `HttpClient`, you could download a file like this:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
try
{       
    // generate a stream on your sever matching the download size requested    
    response = await httpClient.GetAsync(
        "http://www.example.com/speedtest/?size=Large");

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throws exception if bad HTTP status code

    // no reason to measure time to save to file system or store the bytes
    // unnecessarily
    await response.Content.CopyAsAsync(Stream.Null);

}
catch (HttpRequestException hre)
{
    // something went wrong
}
```

Wrap the above with your timing code to compute the download time.

Remember that doing this type of operation, regardless of programming language, may consume a significant and unreasonable amount of a user's data plan. To do an accurate test, you'll need multiple runs as well of very large downloads. One tester I've used for example used 100MB of data.

In the C# code above, you benefit from the fact that it's using a `Null` `Stream` which means that all of the downloaded content is ignored (rather than copied temporarily into a structure like a `byte` array which won't be used).

Given the general flakiness of mobile/cellular networks though, you'll notice great differences between tests.

If you're planning on downloading lots of content with your application, I'd strongly recommend you consider doing more adaptive style techniques. Instead of selecting a network performance number based on a "point-in-time", measure the performance of data downloads with actual application data, and make changes based on that.

In a comment, you mention using the newer [`performanceTiming`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975075) object available in IE10. While you could construct a standards compliant web page, put resources on it, and then use the various events and properties of the object, I think it adds unnecessary overhead and complexity to a Windows Phone application (and the question which was tagged with C#), especially when you're looking to do a specific isolated test. As you cannot control the nature of how the browser downloads the content, you'd need to structure it very carefully to make sure that only the "network speed" measuring resource was downloaded.

Also note that you cannot control other background downloads that may be happening at the time you're running the test, regardless of programming language/platform you're using for building the test.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the solution. The reason I was planning on using javascript was because I am playing around with the new `window.performance.timing` values that may be returned in IE10, and I've seen several samples regarding gathering data and calculating performance statistics based on the results of the Timing API. One thing I haven't come across yet using that data is calculating speed of the connection. I was trying to create my own solution using the time it takes to download a file and the known file size. Would you have any information on how to do this in javascript?

Comment: I don't see how you'd do that efficiently though is why I posted a C# solution. You don't need to use JavaScript and there's no efficient way to dump the response that I'm aware of. Downloading large "blobs" to test network perf in JavaScript is likely to cause an out of memory error in your application.